# Is there anything equivalent to getch() in ksh?

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I am writing a script in Korn Shell, where at one statement I want something like `getch()` used in C.

I want my `while` loop to be exited, if it sees that I have pressed `ESC` in Keyboard.

For eg.

```
while [[ getch() != 27 ]]
do
    print "Hello"
done
```

In my script this `getch() != 27` won't work. I want something there to be worked. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637591/how-to-detect-when-user-press-esc-and-do-something-in-shell-script

Comment: If it's `ksh93` you should look at the KBD trap and `$sh.edchar`. see `man ksh`.

Comment: According to the authors of Unix: Unix is a kernel, libraries, a shell, shell tools, and a C compiler. There for yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `read`

```
x='';while [[ "$x" != "A" ]]; do read -n1 x; done
```

`read -n 1`  is to read 1 character.

This should work in `bash` but you can check if it works in `ksh`

Comment: KSH93 yes, ksh88 no

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/ksh

# KSH function to read one character from standard input
# without requiring a carriage return. To be used in KSH
# script to detect a key press.
#
# Source this getch function into your script by using:
#
# . /path/to/getch.ksh
# or
# source /path/to/getch.ksh
#
# To use the getch command in your script use:
# getch [quiet]
#
# Using getch [quiet] yields no output.

getch()
{
   STAT_GETCH="0"
   stty raw
   TMP_GETCH=`dd bs=1 count=1 2> /dev/null`
   STAT_GETCH="${?}"
   stty -raw

   if [[ "_${1}" != "_quiet" ]]
   then
       print "${TMP_GETCH}"
   fi
   return ${STAT_GETCH}
}
```

Comment: The answer would be improved if there were a few words explaining how it works.

Comment: @ThomasDickey - you don't consider that code speaks for itself? the `stty` restoration ought to be trapped, though, just in case the user manages to somehow interrupt `dd`'s `read()` before it can `getch()` *(as a timed `-icanon` tty might do all its own)*.

Comment: you should also drop the `bs=` there - a character might be more than a byte, and `count=1` will be satisfied as soon as any more than a byte is available at all on a raw mode terminal.